# Pound URL Redirect with negative pattern wouldn't match

Tags: pound

I'm using `Pound(8)` - HTTP/HTTPS reverse-proxy and load-balancer.

```
# rpm -q Pound
Pound-2.6-2.el6.x86_64
#
```

I'd like to be able to redirect certain URL patterns, a user hitting URL `https://www.xxx.tld/` and he/she gets redirected to `http://www.xxx.tld/`.

```
Service
        URL     "^/$"
        Redirect        "http://www.xxx.tld/"
End
```

I'm trying to tweak URL pattern to include *EVERYTHING* BUT certain URL's patterns: like `^/(cart|user)(.*)$`, or actually this: `^(/|(cart|user)(.*))$`.

For whatever reason (perhaps mismatch), Pound is *NOT* redirecting it, and another thing is, let's say user hitting `https://www.xxx.tld/test`, while redirecting user to non https page, I'd like to be able to pass `URI` as well. Is that something I can do w/ Pound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get where I need to be:

```
ListenHTTPS
    Address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    Port    443
    Cert    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/XXXXX.pem"
    Ciphers "ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM"
    Service
        URL     "^/(files|sites|user|cart)(.*)?$"
        BackEnd
                Address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
                Port    443
                HTTPS
        End
        BackEnd
                Address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
                Port    443
                HTTPS
        End
    End
    Service
        URL     "^(/|.*)$"
        Redirect    "http://www.xxx.tld"
    End
End
```