# Redirect all requests to https://www version with Pound proxy

Tags: pound

I am trying to configure Pound proxy configuration file to redirect all requests to a website over http to https://www.example.com. Also I need requests coming to https://example.com to be redirected to https://www.example.com.

I have the following code so far and it works:

```
ListenHTTP
    Address xx.xx.xx.xx
    Port 80

  Service
      HeadRequire "Host:.*example.com.*"
      Redirect "https://www.example.com"
  End

End

Service
    BackEnd
        Address xx.xx.xx.xx
        Port    8888
    End
End
ListenHTTPS
  Cert "/home/path/to/subdomain/ssl.everything"
  Cert "/home/example/ssl.everything"
  Address xx.xx.xx.xx
  Port    443
  HeadRemove "X-Forwarded-Proto"
  AddHeader "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
  Ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384..."
        Service
            URL     "^(/|.*)$"
            Redirect "https://www.example.com"
        End
End
```

However, I can't figure out how to make the rule in ListenHTTP:

```
  Service
      HeadRequire "Host:.*example.com.*"
      Redirect "https://www.example.com"
  End
```

respect other sub-domains of the same domain. Currently unfortunately all the sub-domains also are getting redirected to https://www.example.com.

The same problem for the rule in ListenHTTPS part. It redirects all the requests to https://www.example.com:

```
        Service
            URL     "^(/|.*)$"
            Redirect "https://www.example.com"
        End
```

whereas I need only https://example.com to be redirected to https://www.example.com.

What should be right patterns for bot ListenHTTP and ListenHTTPS blocks to leave out all other domains and sub-domains on the same IP?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/582906/pound-url-redirect-with-negative-pattern-wouldnt-match

Comment: Thanks, but that page is about redirecting https to http. Using the redirect rule in ListenHTTP gives the same result as above - it doesn't take care of desired effect.

Comment: The principle is the same, you can rewrite the rule as you want. Basically - do HTTP to HTTPS redirection first, and then do @ to www.

Comment: Easy to say than implement. I wouldn't bring it here if various approaches were not failing. Mind sharing real code based on the provided above?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind:
The 1st rule to apply WILL be applied!
Basicly you should make a Wildcard-Rule on the very End of the Rule-List.